# Pagination Styling (CSS)

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to change the colour of my active pagination button from black to the light brown (#a88f4b), but it seems as though I can't get rid of the black.  What is it I'm getting wrong here?

http://demo.boxofficeboxing.co.uk/?s=

```
.eltd-pagination a {
color: #666 !important; 
}
.eltd-pagination li.active {
background-color: #a88f4b !important; 
}
.eltd-pagination a:hover {
color: #fff !important; 
background-color: #a88f4b !important;
```

Comment: Seems to work for me. Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your line that should modify:

```
.eltd-pagination ul li a:hover,
.eltd-pagination ul li.active span {
    background-color: #a88f4b !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

In you pagination, active `li` has `span` in it instead `a` tag so you had to set style on the `span` not `li` like code above. copy/paste code above in your css in very last line.